# Render a link field that has a url with query params as a query param (version 7.2)

Tags: links, link-manager

I'm trying to render a link like the following as an external link - however it's cutting off part of the query parameter.

So when I try to render this:

https://www.example.com?url=http://www.another-url.com/?id=1

The href attribute will show as this:

https://www.example.com?url=http://www.another-url.com/

It basically slices at the point where a query string is specified in the query parameter.

Is this a known issue in 7.2 and is there a workaround without resorting to javacript? I've tried url encoding the question mark and the result is the same.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with encoded question mark character? `%3F`? `https://www.example.com?url=http://www.another-url.com/%3Fid=1`

Comment: @MarekMusielak Yes - same result unfortunately

Comment: What's your purpose perhaps we can find a workaround?
Anyway is it a WebForms project?

Comment: No it's MVC, I'm beginning to think it could be an issue with Glass library. It's an external link that uses adfs so it needs a redirect url appending to query string of the query string

Comment: Sean as it is MVC it can be a routing issue. I would consider this too - perhaps the question mark is interpreted as parameter indication

Comment: It's not anything to do with routing as this is an external url - it should simply get the raw url value from the item and render it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vanilla Sitecore code to render a General Link field containing this external Url would be:

```
LinkField lf = myitem.Fields["name of your field"];
string url = lf.GetFriendlyUrl();
```

You should verify this behaviour. It will either work as you expect, or it will be a bug in Sitecore. The string `url` should be exactly as given as value in the Sitecore client.

If it looks like you expect, your issue would be either in Glass - or on how you later pass that url on. E.g. returning it to a view but NOT inside a `HtmlString` or so.

Comment: Thanks, will give the a try tomorrow morning